# how to implement background with multiple color and diagonal form at both side?

Tags: html, css

**My target design**

[image]

**I have this designs** -- [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/284sa/697/) --

I used this method before and after for border.

> ::before SPORTS ::after

for ::after css

```
display: block;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
content: '';
border-color: inherit;
border-top: 0 solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-bottom: 35px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
border-left: 10px solid #f54545;
-ms-box-sizing: border-box;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
```

and i tried all possible css for `::after` like -webkit-border-image, background css etc

How can achieve target design.

Comment: If you've tried using `::before` and `::after`, please post what you've tried in the question. We're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: It's really not clear to me what you are trying to do **but** assuming those colors are meant to be **curved** (it's unclear from the tiny picture) I'd go with a radial gradient and be done with it. If not..then a linear gradient would probably work too.

Comment: I don't see any border radius here ¬¬

Comment: @Paulie_D check my jsfiddle. i want this square area in slant. but i used after and before for slant area.

Comment: Gradient would be the way to go then...still not seeing what this has to do with border-radius.

Comment: If the issue is the diagonal form, maybe this helps http://jsfiddle.net/284sa/698/

Comment: @Danko thanks for your help. i got my solution for your suggestion

Comment: Ok glad to help ... if your answer is solved now and has no answer posted please delete  this one :P .

Comment: @Danko i cant do that, because already i had delete to many times now i am in danger of being blocked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got my solution from danko's [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/284sa/698/) 
Below css is helpful for me

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3333 0%, #ff3333 85%,#3399cc 85%,#3399cc 90%,#ffff66 90%, #ffff66 95%, #ff0099 95%, #ff0099 100%);
width:100%;
height:100%;
-webkit-transform:skewX(-25deg);
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the css that can achieve that:

```
background: #e04f23; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e04f23 0%, #e04f23 80%, #2989d8 80%, #e8cb27 88%, #a227e5 92%, #82e7f2 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%,#e04f23), color-stop(80%,#e04f23), color-stop(80%,#2989d8), color-stop(88%,#e8cb27), color-stop(92%,#a227e5), color-stop(100%,#82e7f2)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e04f23 0%,#e04f23 80%,#2989d8 80%,#e8cb27 88%,#a227e5 92%,#82e7f2 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e04f23 0%,#e04f23 80%,#2989d8 80%,#e8cb27 88%,#a227e5 92%,#82e7f2 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, #e04f23 0%,#e04f23 80%,#2989d8 80%,#e8cb27 88%,#a227e5 92%,#82e7f2 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(135deg, #e04f23 0%,#e04f23 80%,#2989d8 80%,#e8cb27 88%,#a227e5 92%,#82e7f2 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e04f23', endColorstr='#82e7f2',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
```

Comment: It's the same as the linear-gradient but with implementation issues taken care of and the transforms also taken care of. It almost the same css but repeated over for different browsers. If you look at it, it's not hard to decipher what's going on